# the opposite of subdivide

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

[image]

So i was wandering is there a way to transform object 2 into object 1, without going into edit mode and deleting all extra vertice from object 2
i tried the un-subdivide option but it did something else :/ help please.

Comment: This is called 'Limited Dissolve'. You'll find it in the Clean up menu.

Comment: i'm pretty sure this has been asked before, but can't find the exact duplicate

Comment: not a bad question @xlxs, just it seem this has been asked already -- unless you can edit your question to make it some how unique

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to zeffi's comment i was able to figure out a better way that decimate modifier, with almost none shape changes.
1)select mesh
2) go to edit mode
3) select all vertice
4)press delete and click limited dissolve
this will maintain the geometry but will get rid of non used vectice

Answer (score 2):

The [decimate modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/generate/decimate.html) can do this, though it doesn't always work quite like you want it to.

**Blender Reference Manual, Decimate Modifier**

> The Decimate modifier allows you to reduce the vertex/face count of a mesh with minimal shape changes....The Decimate modifier is a quick and easy way of reducing the polygon count of a mesh non-destructively. This modifier demonstrates the advantages of a mesh modifier system because it shows how an operation which is normally permanent and destroys original mesh data, can be done interactively and safely using a modifier.